# Is it possible to take the input and run it through a string and print it the way I am?

Tags: python-3.x

Why can't it output an answer when I tell it to "makeChange(change)"? I want the program to take the user input and take it and go through the string and break it down into change. Is it possible for you to make it print the function?

```
def makeChange(amount):
      
      coins = [.05, .1, .25, .5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
    
      coins.sort(reverse=True) 
    
      change = float(input("What do ya want to break down?")) #This is where I want the user to input a number.
      change = []
      for coin in coins:
        totalCoin = int(float(amount) // coin)
        amount = amount % coin
        amount = round(amount, 2)
        for i in range(totalCoin):
          change.append(coin)
        if amount == 0:
          return change
      return 'Not changeable'
                                                        #             \/
    print('Here is your change!: ', makeChange(change)) #makeChange(change) this is where I want the user input to go through the string come out with the answer of what the user inputted into change.
```

Comment: When you are prompting the user and setting `change` what is the purpose of this as you immediately reset change to an empty array?

Comment: Try to fix the indentation. Your `print()` statement for example is called within scope of the `makeChange` function after the return and thus basically unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
def makeChange(amount):

    coins = [.05, .1, .25, .5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

    coins.sort(reverse=True)

    change = []
    for coin in coins:
        totalCoin = int(float(amount) // coin)
        amount = amount % coin
        amount = round(amount, 2)
        for i in range(totalCoin):
            change.append(coin)
        if amount == 0:
            return change
    return 'Not changeable'


change = float(input("What do ya want to break down?"))
print('Here is your change!: ', makeChange(change))
```

A function isn't run until it is called. You were then calling the function with an undefined variable of change.

I suggest reading more about scopes to better understand this.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp